# Why were so many nominations greyed out?

Tags: support, election

On the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=nomination) many nominations appear grey and are locked (no commenting possible), were those retracted by the authors or what happened to them?

**Update:**

The previously greyed-out nominations are not visible on the election page anymore. For transparency's sake I would still like to know what happened there and why those nominations were disabled.

Comment: I hoped to find enlightenment by reading the class list... then I saw is an attribute with _some opacity setting __jQuery__ on it!_ Now I am enlightened (still I can't answer this question).

Comment: Perhaps it was rejected by an existing moderator (due to low quality, no qualifications, etc.) and due for removal after some period of time?

Comment: I'm guessing they did a self-delete after and it's in the removal queue.

Comment: @Jeff I would hope not, rejecting applications without explanation is not the most democratic behaviour. If they are removed by the team I expect it will be explained shortly.

Comment: @Fabian: I'm only speculating but it's still open for editing probably, only greyed out because of the low quality and doesn't need that kind of attention.  At least the person can find the nomination and update it to meet standards or make a case in comments.  If sufficiently updated, it would be returned back to normal.

Comment: There was a typo on the page that gave the rep requirement as **300** rather than **3000**, so a number of people posted nominations in good faith that no longer qualify. There were also a number of blank nominations.

Comment: Has anyone looked at how long each person has been a member of SO?  It could be a requirement related to account age.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's doesn't explain it.  User "dogbane" has nearly 10k rep and he's greyed out.

Comment: @Pollyanna: Account age doesn't seem to be the problem either.  User "dogbane"'s account is 2 years, 4 months.

Comment: Oh, well then it's probably "At least 3k rep, 1 year old account, and not dogbane"

Comment: @raven: dogbane's nomination text was [blank initially](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4729558/revisions) which ended up being grayed out.  He did eventually add something to it but the damage was done I think.  If he was serious about it, he could probably nominate himself again or at least make a case with the team to be put back.

Comment: I saw about every other one greyed out, but now I don't see that anymore.  Maybe it is fixed?  Still wonder if it was on purpose at all?

Comment: @jzd It seems those previously greyed-out posts are not there anymore. Some are certainly gone due to not having enough rep for the top 30, but at least the nomination from the 9k user should still be in there if that was the only reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ChrisF said:

> There was a typo on the page that gave the rep requirement as 300 rather than 3000, so a number of people posted nominations in good faith that no longer qualify. There were also a number of blank nominations.

withdrawn nominations show in that state, but there are additional considerations in play because there are > 30 nominations.